# Is it possible to implement Oauth 1.0 through just javascript without any server side script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, flickr

I am trying to develop a Jquery plugin for Flickr photo exploring. But i am stuck on authenticating user. Flickr support Oauth 1.0.

My question is do you think there is any way to implement Oauth 1.0 with just Javascript? "With just Javascript" means I cannot use any server side script. I have to make all the request through Ajax. You know Ajax has cross origin restriction and from my experiment the links for Oauth don't allow CORS/jsonp.

Comment: If it's client-size javascript only, I think you'll run into CORS issue, but worst you'll be exposing your secret key in javascript when you need to create the signatures for the oauth requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. This is one of the reasons OAuth 2.0 was born.

https://blog.apigee.com/detail/oauth_differences

> For instance, OAuth 2.0 also clearly lays out how to use OAuth entirely inside a browser using JavaScript that has no way to securely store a token, and it explains at a high level how to use it on a mobile phone or even on a device that has no web browser at all.